# Applying a FontFamily to all Controls in Silverlight 4 Beta

Tags: silverlight, controls, fonts, silverlight-4.0, styles

I'd like to give every `Control` a certain `FontFamily` and `FontWeight` in Silverlight 4.0. I know that styles can now apply to all controls of a certain type, so I tried this:

```
<Style TargetType="Control">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
</Style>
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to work. I can do this for types that derive from `Control`, however. For example, setting `TargetType` to `Button` applies those values to every `Button` in my application.

Why can't I do this for the `Control` base class, then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The control styling being tied to the type system can be a bit misleading.  Its actually based on the value of the controls `DefaultStyleKey` property.  In the case of a `Button` the value is `typeof(Button)` and for a `TextBox` it is `typeof(Textbox)`.

A default style will be applied to a control if the `TargetType` value equals the controls `DefaultStyleKey` value.  There is no examination of whether the `Type` in the `DefaultStyleKey` is a derivative of the `TargetType`.

Font related properties are a special case since most controls will inherit the values for Font properties from the containing context.  Hence you can effectively acheive the same result by specifying `FontFamily` and `FontWeight` on the UserControl element.

**Edit**

From a comment by the OP:-

> I was hoping that I could set it in one place and have every UserControl in the entire application take on that style.

The closest you can get to that is to place a keyed style in the app resources and ensure all the usercontrols bind to that style.  Of course this still requires some co-operation for each user control but at least the font choices remain in a single place.

For example in app.xaml:-

```
<Style x:Key="Common" TargetType="UserControl">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
```

Then in each usercontrol:-

```
<UserControl ...namespace stuff here...
   Style="{StaticResource Common}">
  <!-- ... content here ... -->
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Although I was hoping that I could set it in one place and have every UserControl in the entire application take on that style. I guess I could make a custom UserControl to base the others on, though.

Answer (score 1):

I do it by specifying FontFamily in my root visual. All child controls without explicit FontFamily set, derive FontFamily from the root visual.

Only ChildWindow needs extra FontFamily setting, because it is hosted in "über" root visual (as popup).

Comment: what's the xaml you do the setting with? root visual doesn't take styles.

Answer (score 1):

This would be of help:

```cs
this.RootVisual = New MainPage();
(MainPage)this.RootVisual.FontFamily 
  = New System.Windows.Media.FontFamily(
    "/SLApplication;component/Fonts/segoeui.ttf#Segoe UI");
```